# Падающий снег в SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Цель: падающий снег
Библиотека: SFML
Ошибка: снег падает, но только при условии ,что я что-либо делаю в окне приложения(двигаю мышкой, нажимаю клавиши). Как только я перестаю что-то подобное делать снег просто останавливается.

Так изменяются координаты в методе update.

```
        y += 1;
        switch (rand() % 3 + 1)
        {
         case 1:
             x += 1;
             break;
         case 2:
             x -= 1;
             break;
         case 3:
             x = x;
             break;
        }
```

Так выглядит гейм-цикл.

```
 while (window.isOpen())
{

    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {...}
        for (auto& element : snow)         //Тут в цикле идём по всем снежинкам и выполняем для них update
        {
            if (!(*element).update(time))
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < del; ++i)
            snow.pop_front();
        for (auto element : snow)           //Тут идём по списку snow и прорисовываем каждую снежинку
            window.draw((*element).cirkl);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Собственно,что мне сделать,чтобы независимо от пользователя снег падал.

Comment: по коду не совсем понятно, отрисовка находится внутри цикла while (window.pollEvent(event)) или нет. Если она втрутри, тогда это и есть Ваша проблема

Comment: судя по описанию проблемы у вас просто отрисовка привязана к циклу обработки эвентов - стандартная проблема у новичков (сам с таким сталкивался). Вам необходимо реализовать обработку эвентов и отрисовку независимо. Это можно сделать несколькими вариантами, например делать это в разных потоках, но это может добавить проблем (синхронизация и т.д.), а можно сделать все в одном потоке, но для этого нужно операция по получению эвентов должна вызываться с таймаутом (время между отрисовкой двух кадров). Как то так

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, спасибо огромное, действительно, стандартная проблема новичка))
Ещё. Я на этом сайте недавно, не знаком с его политикой. Что делать с вопросом ,если получил на него ответ? Просто удалить?

Comment: @СашаШумейко нет, вопрос и ответ остаются, просто ответ отмечается как верный - расчет на то что он поможет не только вам. Но сдесь нет ответа - я оставил комментарий, так как из вопроса было не совсем ясна проблема и я высказал предположение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моём случае помог один из комментариев.

> судя по описанию проблемы у вас просто отрисовка привязана к циклу обработки эвентов - стандартная проблема у новичков (сам с таким сталкивался). Вам необходимо реализовать обработку эвентов и отрисовку независимо. Это можно сделать несколькими вариантами, например делать это в разных потоках, но это может добавить проблем (синхронизация и т.д.), а можно сделать все в одном потоке, но для этого нужно операция по получению эвентов должна вызываться с таймаутом (время между отрисовкой двух кадров). Как то так

Отрисовка была привязана к циклу обработки эвентов. Для решения проблемы просто перенём её в другое место - в game-цикл.

Comment: хорошо не только комент перепостить а и написать, где именно была проблема и как именно ее исправили